# Redis session is refreshing on every new request from Angular HTTP GET, but NOT from Browser

Tags: node.js, angular, session, redis

I implemented a Redis session store with NodeJS (+ express). This is the code for the session:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
const redisClient = redis.createClient(config.redis);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'SomeSecretKey',
    key: 'session_id',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, secure: false},
    store: new redisStore({
            host: config.redis.host,
            port: config.redis.port,
            client: redisClient,
            ttl: 86400
        }
    ),
}));
```

My route `/api/session` looks like the following in NodeJS: (I'm manipulating the session object and append some values to it)

```
app.get('/api/session', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.sessionID);
    req.session.test = 42;
    res.end('1');
});
```

When I go to `localhost:3000/api/session` via Browser, I get the following on my `redis-cli monitor`:

[image]

Like you see in the screenshot - the session ID is keeping the same.

But when I do the GET Request from Angular HTTP Module via:

[image]

then my `redis-cli monitor` shows the following (it is generating a new sessionID for every request, and I can not store any data inside the session):

[image]

So summarized: GET Request from browser DOES store my session, but from Angular HTTP module the GET Request DOES NOT store my session. Further with Angular GET Request it DOES NOT store the session_id in my application cookie (when I press F12 in Chrome).

**EDIT:**
When I do `curl localhost:3000/api/session` it does the same like Angular HTTP module: New session for every request. I want to have a persistent session with the same sessionID.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who has also run into this issue: after hours of reading, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193283/what-am-i-missing-about-express-sessions-and-cookies) thread, where user `FlavorScape` posted his accepted answer with the hint at the end of his code example. The following steps solved my issue:

**1** I've changed the session in NodeJS to the following options:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'SomeSecretKey',
    key: 'session_id',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {maxAge: 60000, rolling: true,},
    store: new redisStore({host: config.redis.host, port: config.redis.port, client: redisClient, ttl: 86400}),
}));
```

**2** Set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in NodeJS to the origin of your frontend application:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

**3** That's the most important part I guess: In Your Angular application, set `withCredentials: true` in the GET options

```
getUserSession(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.config.ENDPOINT_URL + 'session', {withCredentials: true});
}
```